# Windows: print simple vector graphics - example?

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, vector-graphics, polygons

I want to print some vector graphics (or to be more exact: nothing more than some polylines) using Windows API. Printing has to be done out of an own thread.

When I ask Google/MSDN for some code-snippets or examples I mainly find documentation how to print using some WindowsForms/.NET crap, but no WinAPI examples. Or I find a really *huge* example of XPS printing provided by MS which is very confusing and does much more than only sending some data to printer.

So my question: is there a simple example somewhere that demonstrates how to print out some stupid lines?

Comment: Yes, there are MANY examples...in C#/.NET/WindowsForms. And there is ONE C/C++ example in MSDN that is huge, confusing and contains many crap around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the traditional GDI functions to do this, you have two main steps:

- First, learn to use GDI functions to draw in your own window. Some functions in this category include [PolyLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [LineTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and so on.
- Next, getting it to work with a printer. It's really the same concept as drawing to the screen, except you instead get a HDC that represents a portion of a page rather than a portion of screen - plus there's more setup and cleanup involved. When drawing on screen, you can just get the window DC, draw, and you're done; printing to a page is more involved - you have to select a printer, start a document, start a page, and so on.

I found [this fairly decent tutuorial on Win32 GDI printing](http://win32-framework.sourceforge.net/Tutorials/tutorial9.htm) that might work for you - it covers all the setup/cleanup steps. One thing to watch for is that it sends a bitmap to the printer; instead you would want to replace the `StretchDIBits` call with your own `PolyLine` etc calls.

Comment: Yay! - For what it's worth, I found it by googling for `startpage startdoc win32 example` or similar - I'm familiar enough with Win32 to know the key functions that it had to have, and then this turned up as the second match.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic GDI functionality. Have a look at the [GDI line drawing functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145031%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN. Note that most languages and environments have their own wrappers around GDI that provide the same functionality.